# linking an onkeypress event with an if else statement?

Tags: javascript, html, onkeypress

I am having an issue linking an event to an if else statement. I was able to get an onkeypress event that changed the html content but I am having issues getting the content of what key was pressed after the event to run some code if they pressed a certain key. If you could help me figure out why my code isn't working that would be great. I am getting no syntax errors. I want it to console.log when I press the key "h".

**HTML**

```
    <p>Guess what letter I'm thinking of!</p>
    <br/ >
    <div>Wins: </div>
    <br/ >
    <p id="losses">Losses: </p>
    <br/ >
    <p>Guesses Left: </p>
    <br/ >
    <p>Your Guesses so far: <span id="change"></span></p>
    <br/ >
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function() {

var guess = document.body.onkeypress = function(event){
document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
}

  function test(){
  var letter = document.getElementById('change');

    if(letter.innerHTML==="h"){
        console.log('hi');
    } else {
        console.log("nothing");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: when test is executed?

Comment: @JesusCarrasco I am trying to make it so when you press h, it does a console.log(); It already changes the content of the html to whatever key you press.  Sorry I am still new to java

Comment: try my answer, and let me know if help.    do yo mean javascript. ?lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me i did not found in your code the invoke of test function so i wrapped in the onkeypress

```
    var guess = document.body.onkeypress = function(event){
        console.log(event);
        document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = 
        String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
        var letter = document.getElementById('change');
        if(letter.innerHTML==="h"){
          console.log('hi');
        } else {
          console.log("nothing");
      }

  };
```

Comment: Oh my! Thank you! Was working on this for several hours and couldnt figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` elements don't have any HTML content, so `innerHTML` always returns an empty string.

You can get the value of the textbox (not just the character, if any, that the user pressed) with `.value`.

Comment: I changed it to value and it didn't work. It also isn't a text box though. I have it set up so it changes the text in the div.

Comment: I mean input box